# mysql innodb vs MyISAM

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, innodb, myisam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MyISAM versus InnoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148/myisam-versus-innodb)

Hi there,

In MySQL, which storage engine is faster? InnoDB or MyISAM?
Can any one list their +/- here?
not detailed list but in short.

Thanks.

Comment: http://tag1consulting.com/MySQL_Engines_MyISAM_vs_InnoDB

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InnoDB

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970420/how-much-faster-is-myisam-compared-to-innodb

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251179/mysql-innodb-vs-myisam

Comment: a search of SO would pretty much answer your question....

Comment: check out innodb clustered indexes which most people overlook or fail to mention : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419499/mysql-nosql-help-me-to-choose-the-right-one-on-a/4421601#4421601

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can get a definitive answer.  I *think* MyISAM is faster for many simple queries, however, it only has table-level locks.  InnoDB, on the other-hand uses row-locking, which could mean things are faster when you are running multiple large queries concurrently.