# What is the fastest MariaDB storage engine for reads?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, myisam

I have a table in a MariaDB database with 125 million rows that is used to store results from automated data analyses. A few thousand rows are written at random times each day. Queries on the table happen several times a day, and could return a few thousand or a few million results. The read performance is most important, because that happens in front of the user.

Currently I use MyISAM, which works generally well, except when the result set gets above a few thousand rows. I have indexes on the columns that are used for querying. The query cache helps, but it's rare that a user will perform the same search more than once.

I'm sure there are many optimization techniques I could use (I'd love to hear those too!), but the most basic question is with a table of this size and this usage pattern, what is the best MariaDB storage engine for the table?

Comment: Did you tried to google it?

Comment: Yes. There are lots of sort-of relevent articles, mostly related to writes, but none that answer this question about the fastest table for reads.

Comment: [Read about this on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970420/how-much-faster-is-myisam-compared-to-innodb)

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/17434

Comment: show the read query, the table definition and sample data or put a sample on http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: With 125,000,000 rows? :-)

Comment: you can also put piece of the data at pastebin (1000/10000 rows). then i can download it and test it local. i am also want to know wich MySQL version you are using

Comment: The fastest storage engine is MEMORY.

Comment: @Georg Richter - The Storage Engine Memory has many restriction and we not know wich datatype he use. Memory dosent support Text and Blob fields

Comment: After doing some testing (by copying my table, changing the engine, and running various queries on both). It seems that for my data, the Aria engine works well. Even at 125million rows, it's 2-10x faster at select queries than the MyISAM.

Comment: @GregB - Did you also try InnoDB?  Will you be having _concurrent_ reads? 
 MyISAM will do poorly when mixing reads and writes; is that infrequent enough not to matter?  What indexes can be used?  That may be a big issue.  Seeing a sample query would help.

Comment: @GregB - The QC slows things down if you make it too big.  You should probably turn it off, regardless of Engine.  How much RAM?

Comment: @GregB - "except when the result set gets above a few thousand rows" and "indexes on the columns" -- These sound contradictory; let's see the `CREATE TABLE` and such an index.  Do you use Summary tables?

Comment: @GregB - "I'd love to hear those too!" -- I have lots of those, but so far your question is too general for me to launch into optimization techniques.  It smells like these might be relevant:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql and http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

Answer (score 2):

The index implementation between the Engines is different enough to prevent answering your question without seeing the actual query and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

InnoDB is the fastest engine for virtually all use cases.  How much RAM do you have?  How big is your table?  Part of what I am fishing for is whether your queries are CPU-bound or I/O-bound.

Depending on the details of the query, taking advantage of InnoDB's "clustered" `PRIMARY KEY` can give a boost.  This is not directly available in MyISAM.

What are you doing with the thousand or million rows?  Summarizing?  If so, then there is an approach that may make the queries run 10 times as fast:  https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables